# Best solution to pass massive messaging spikes to AWS SQS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webhooks

The app I'm working on is expected to face occasional spikes of incoming messages to be processed (Facebook webhook events). Live tests of this app hasn't been done yet but based on the experience of similar projects it's expected that these spikes can start sharply and hold at ~0.8-3k messages/sec for several hours. Beginning of the spike is predictable to the accuracy of several seconds-tens of seconds.

It's seems rational to pass these messages to some queue like AWS SQS and then process them at comfortable speed. If so, what would be the optimal solution for resending such message waves to SQS so that the listening app is always available, especially in the beginning of the spike (otherwise Facebook can probably show 503 error "Your webhook is down"):

- hosting the listening app on AWS EC2 with a load balancer;
- hosting the listening app on AWS Lambda (probably implementing some Lambda-warming measures like [these](https://www.jeremydaly.com/lambda-warmer-optimize-aws-lambda-function-cold-starts/))
- other ideas? It would have been convenient if SQS could confirm subscription to Messenger webhooks so that Facebook would send those messages directly to SQS but that's unfortunately not possible due to "passive" nature of SQS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Summary: Thank you A.Khan and matsev (and also David M. for an email) for your answers. We'll probably start with a loadbalancer with several EC2 instances beyond it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

> hosting the listening app on AWS EC2 with a load balancer

I think you can simplify it by going Serverless.

> hosting the listening app on AWS Lambda (probably implementing some Lambda-warming measures

I don't think Lambda will be a good option because of 1000 concurrent executions limit, although it can be increased.

> other ideas? It would have been convenient if SQS could confirm subscription to Messenger webhooks so that Facebook would send those messages directly to SQS but that's unfortunately not possible due to "passive" nature of SQS

I'd suggest using AWS API Gateway with AWS Service integration using SQS. You can configure 
Facebook webhook events to go directly to your API Gateway REST endpoint. You can configure authentication and throttling as per your requirements in API gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I like the architecture with a thin frontend application whose only responsibility is to accept the incoming request and immediately offload it to a queue or a stream. At the other end of the stream, there is a worker application that take care of the actually event processing.

> other ideas?

Personally, I would use API Gateway mapped to Kinesis (or Kinesis Firehose) for the frontend application instead of EC2. Thus, I can rely on AWS to provide load balancing, autoscaling, OS patches, network configuration and so on. Moreover, Kinesis offers significant buffering capabilities so there is no need to resend the message spike. For the worker part of the application, it depends on what action needs to be performed. For short-lived operations, I recommend Lambda, but AWS also offers integration with EMR, Redshift, Elasticsearch and so on.